# Getting error when sending command action

Tags: asterisk-java

In latest snap-shot of asterisk-java lib (ver-3.0.2) when sending wrapper action of CommandAction through AsteriskPBX i get an error of "invalid command" no matter what command is passed. In a particular case, I send "queue show".It works with "normal" CommandAction through ConnectionManager though.

Is there something just I need to fix or is it known bug?
If so could you suggest an alternative to this action?

Piece of code here:

```
CommandAction command = new CommandAction("queue show");
pbx.sendAction(command);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your question to Stackoverflow! It looks like there might be some incorrect and incomplete information here though. There does not seem to be a version 3.0.2 listed in Asterisk-Java's GitHub repository (which you can also browse to see if other users have run into a similar issue). https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java

From the small snippet you shared, it may be that you are trying to send a type of `Action` that is not understood by the `ConnectionManager`? It looks like all the `Action` type classes inherit from one another so the compiler may not catch this.

Comment: Well according pom of cloned project from [ https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java.git]   the version is  3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.  Although i'm sending CommandAction which is in org.asteriskjava.pbx.asterisk.wrap.actions package.And interface i'm sending through this action is AsteriskPBX in the same package as well.